# When a functions return value can be of many types (using |) how can I pick one in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-keychain

I'm building an app using React Native with TypeScript. I'm writing my own custom wrapper around a function of the React Native Keychain package.

```
export const getToken = () => getGenericPassword().then(creds => creds.password);
```

The problem is that the type of `getGenericPassword()` is:

```
function getGenericPassword(
  options?: Options
): Promise<boolean | {service: string, username: string, password: string}>;
```

And my linter complains that the key password does not exist if creds is of type `boolean`.

```
Property 'password' does not exist on type 'boolean | { service: string; username: string; password: string; }'.
  Property 'password' does not exist on type 'false'.
```

How can I pick one of these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value is a Boolean, it doesn't have those properties. You have to first handle the case that the result is a Boolean:

```
if (typeof creds == "boolean") {
    // Handle a boolean result
} else {
    // You can access the fields here
}
```

TypeScript understands that inside the `if` branch the result is a boolean and inside the `else` branch it's not, so it must be your dictionary type.

If Typescript didn't work like this, you could write code that ignores the case that the promise returns a Boolean, and you'd cause a  runtime problem later when you try to read `.password` from a `false`